# C parsing input text file into words

Tags: c, split, strtok

I am trying to parse input file (containing a text document with multiple lines and delimiters, i.e. "!,.?") into words. My function 'splitting function' is:

```
int splitInput(fp) {

    int i= 0;
    char  line[255];
    char *array[5000];
    int x;
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL) {     
        array[i] = strtok(line, ",.!? \n");
        printf("Check print - word %i:%s:\n",i, array[i]);
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And? What is the problem? What is the expected output? What do you actually get?

Comment: Read the man page for strtok: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

Comment: @gopi: How is strtok supposed to know which string to split, when you only send it NULL? You have to call strtok first with a pointer to the string you wish to split. Then you call it repeatedly with NULL, to get more tokens.

Comment: Yes, sorry - I've just realized it. It still doesn't work - even with 'line' replacing NULL.

Comment: _It still doesn't work_ Be specific. Is anything printing? Also, you need to call `strok` repeatedly until it returns `NULL` (first time with `line` as 1st parameter then with `NULL` as parameter.

Comment: @gopi: You need a loop for strtok, but not one that reads a completely new string from the user in each iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the corrected function [sorry for extra the style cleanup]:

```
int
splitInput(fp)
{
    int i = 0;
    char *cp;
    char *bp;
    char line[255];
    char *array[5000];
    int x;

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL) {
        bp = line;
        while (1) {
            cp = strtok(bp, ",.!? \n");
            bp = NULL;

            if (cp == NULL)
                break;
            array[i++] = cp;

            printf("Check print - word %i:%s:\n",i-1, cp);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now, take a look at the man page for `strtok` to understand the `bp` trick

Comment: @gopi You're welcome!  I never give just "well you should check manpage"--pedantic/frustrating/useless for someone who has already made an honest effort like you.  One way to teach is to give a hint or two:  "you need an inner loop and look at strtok first arg closely".  Better.  But, I think people learn more with a complete solution [and easier for me--this comment is taking longer than the code :-)].  And, that's how I learned:  reading others' code and asking "Why did they do _that_?".  Anyway, happy programming!!!

Comment: Exactly. I was simply stuck & needed a push. Thanks a lot - much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want to read every line and split each line into words and add that into an array.

```
    array[i] = strtok(line, ",.!? \n");
```

That will not work for obvious reasons because it will only return the first word for each line and you never allocate memory.

This is probably what you want.

```
    char *pch;
    pch = strtok(line, ",.!? \n");
    while(pch != NULL) {
      array[i++] = strdup(pch); // put the content of pch into array at position i and increment i afterwards.
      pch = strtok(NULL, ",.!? \n"); // look for remaining words at the same line
    }
```

Don't forget to free your array elements afterwards though using `free`.

Comment: @gopi great, don't forget to remove your increment of `i` after the `printf` because that will be redundant.